# Microsoft Sync Framework Adding Columns to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a live website using the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1, I need to make enhancements which involves adding a new column to one of the existing database tables. I need to know how you go about adding this new column to the Sync Framework so any changes made in this column are also recorded. I am new to using the Sync Framework, so any information will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sync framework doesn't support modifying the scope definition, you will have to hack the sync framework created objects to reflect the new column... have a look at a sample [here](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-3-workarounds-addingremoving-columns/)